# Django Terms and Conditions form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to figure out the most elegant way to build a terms and conditions (TNC)form using django.  The user has to agree to the TNC in order to continue.  The confusing part is how embed a scrolling text field into the form with the TNC that is not editable.  Then the user has to click the check box or the form is invalid.   The TNC is a substantial doc and is located in a text file.  Is there a way to load the text file and make that the content of the scrolling field.

Any examples of this type of form or something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> The confusing part is how embed a scrolling text field into the form with the TNC that is not editable.

This confusing part is easy: it's not a form element. It's just text.

Get your content somehow... say from a file as you suggest:

```
context = {}
with open('/terms-and-conditions.txt') as f:
    context['terms'] = f.read()
```

Define a simple form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    i_agree = forms.BooleanField()
```

Pass both to your template...

```
<div style="width:600px; height:300px; overflow-y:scroll;">
    {% if form.errors %}
        <h1>You must agree to the TNC</h1>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="I agree to the TNC" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Anything else is just a permutation of this simple pattern. Perhaps you use readonly textarea, a javascript warning, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to combine the TNC with MyForm?    The reason I ask is that MyForm gets rendered as part of a multi-step SessionWizard.

Comment: Why not make the data an attribute on the form and pull it in the template? It's just a python object..

Comment: Remember to include {% csrf_token %} in the template. Not sure when the token was first introduced but it will throw up an error in this era.